# Collection of Xtext Grammars as a library?

Tags: antlr4, xtext

I am wondering if there is a library containing different grammar languages defined using Xtext, similar to the one available for Antlr v4 [Antlr v4 Grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4). This would enable reuse and help reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing, at least not as a single, integrated repository. 
In the official documentation, there are the ["Seven Languages In Seven Weeks" examples](https://github.com/xtext/seven-languages-xtext).

But depending on what you are trying to achieve, a basic grammar like [Xbase](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/305_xbase.html) or a textual modelling language like [Xcore](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Xcore) may serve your purpose. Other than that, you can [search for real-life examples on Github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=grammar%20extension%3Axtext&type=Code).